# Flutter MapView instance issue. Cannot see the markers second time

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view#-example-tab-) package to display maps on two consecutive pages.
when I open the mapview on first page I'm able to see the markers and then when I open the mapview on next page it also works fine but then when I get back to the first page again and open the mapview then it shows nothing all the markers are gone.

[Video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i45KvxOx5tk&feature=youtu.be)

```
_mapView.show(
          new MapOptions(
            showMyLocationButton: true,
            showCompassButton: true,
            mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
            showUserLocation: true,
            initialCameraPosition:
                new CameraPosition(new Location(_lat, _lang), 15.0),
            title:
                '_title',
          ),
          toolbarActions: [
            _buildToolBarActionsMaps(),
            ToolbarAction("X", 1),
          ],
        );
        List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[
          new Marker(
              "1",
              "Text",
              _lat,
              _lang,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              markerIcon: new MarkerIcon('assets/marker.png',
                  height: 80.0, width: 80.0)),
        ];
         StreamSubscription sub = _mapView.onMapReady.listen((_) {
          // setState(() {
            _mapView.setMarkers(markers);
          // });
        });                                             compositeSubscription.add(sub);
      sub = _mapView.onToolbarAction.listen((id) {
        if (id == 1) {
          _mapView.dismiss();
          compositeSubscription.cancel();
        }
      });
      compositeSubscription.add(sub);
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @yashthakkar1173 added the code. please review once. I've also tried adding listeners to composite subscription and canceling it at the time of dismissing the map but that also didn't help.

Comment: I guess onMapReady ready is not called again when I open the map second time.

Comment: In code add setState method by uncommenting it and try again!! i thing it'll work.

Comment: I've tried both ways. it didn't work.